# django form: how to check out checkbox state in template

Tags: django, checkbox, django-templates, django-forms

I have a form with checkboxes that works fine, but when the user submits the form with errors and my checkbox is checked I need to change div class which holds the checkbox. So I was experimenting with `{{ form.mycheckbox.data }}` in the template and it says **False** on page load. Now when user is click on a checkbox and the form has errors, it says **on**. So I tried:

`{{ if form.mycheckbox.data == True }}` doesn't work

`{{ if form.mycheckbox.data != False }}` doesn't work

`{{ if form.mycheckbox.data == 'on' }}` doesn't work

`{{ if form.mycheckbox.data == on }}` doesn't work

Comment: I was make typo with div class name, =='on' works. Sorry

Answer (score 23):

Use `{% if form.mycheckbox.value %}`. This will evaluate to true if the box is checked.  For the opposite behavior, use `{% if not form.mycheckbox.value %}`.

Note the syntax is `{% if ... %}`, not `{{ if ...}}`.  Percent-brackets are for commands, double-brackets are for outputting variables.

Answer (score 19):

In models.py:

```
class Article:
    published = BooleanField()
    (...)
```

In the template:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="published" {% if article.published %}checked{% endif %} />
```

Answer (score 7):

Work for me:

```
{% for foo in form.tags %}
  <label class="publication-tag">
    <input class="publication-tag__checkbox"
      {% if foo.choice_value in foo.value %}checked="checked"{% endif %}
      type="checkbox" 
      name="{{ foo.name }}"
      value="{{ foo.choice_value }}">
{% endfor %}
```

That:

```
{% if foo.choice_value in foo.value %}checked="checked"{% endif %}
```

Comment: A correction to the above `if condition` is `{% if foo.choice_value in forms.tags.value %}checked="checked"{% endif %}`

Comment: `{% if foo.choice_value in foo.value %}` This works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

While, first you should use BooleanField in your model, not the CharField.
Then, there are two accesses:

- just put {{form.yourField}} in your template (preferred)
- or, use {% if form.yourFiled.value %} checked {%endif%}